# Matlab Pow2 function gives INF result

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Suppose that:
a=5.7675e+07

when i execute **pow2(a)**, it gives me **INF**. While
when i execute **a*a** or **a^2**, it gives me **5.7675e+07**.

how to explain this?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `pow2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pow2.html)?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing about my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow2(a)` returns `2^a`, not `a^2`.